# Use a custom stencil as fillpattern with VBA for Visio shapes

Tags: vba, visio

I am working on a vba macro that changes the fillpattern of various shapes depending on their name. I made some custom stencils (named "test") in another .vssx file and I try to use these stencils as fillpattern, without success.
When I check the vsoShp1.CellsU("FillPattern").FormulaU of my shape after I applied the custom stencil manualy, I get "USE("test")". But I do not understand how to select this FillPattern with vba code...

Here is a part of my code :

```
For Each vsoPage In vsoDoc.Pages 
    Set vsoDoc = vsoApp.Documents.Open(File.Path)
    'Path of the .vssx file
    strNewPath = local_path
    Favoris = local_path & "\Favoris.vssx"
    'Loading the .vssx file in a current open visio doc
    Dim vsoDocNew As Visio.Document
    Set vsoDocNew = vsoApp.Documents.OpenEx(Favoris, visOpenDocked + visAddStencil)
    'Use the custom stencil for each shapes in the page
    For Each vsoShp1 In vsoPage.Shapes
         vsoShp1.CellsU("FillPattern").FormulaU = "test"
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks to the macro recorder, the solution is: 
vsoShp1.CellsU("FillPattern").FormulaU = "USE(""test"")"

Comment: Now, I can select the FillPattern, but it did not show the correct pattern on the visio file (I think I have to add the Stencil in the main master first)